# How can I secure implement third-party API calls using JavaScript in a BigcCommerce store?

Tags: javascript, api, post, bigcommerce

I want to make some API requests to the shipping carriers at the BigCommerce product page and I have some credential for that requests which I don't want to show in my JS code. According to the specific environment of BigCommerce I can't make any changes in back end code. I read a lot of similar questions and now have only one question.

Is it only one way to do that using my own API back end web-server which will store credential information and send POST request to the third party API? Then I will receive that information using a POST request via JS to my own API.

I have tried to run Ruby API application on the nginx web-server. However, it was unsuccessful because browser blocked my fetch() request according to the CORS Policy. I tried to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * parameter to the server response header writing it in ruby config file but browser didn't recognize it. Also I tried to set up configuration file on the nginx side but that didn't help me with CORS policy response. That's interesting because using Restlet Application I received response from my own API application with correct information and status "ok".

```
(async function application() {
  let dataRuby = {
     url: 'http://IP_address/index',
     body: {"name": "21312", "year": "2019"}
  };
  function getApi(data) {
     let myInit = {};
     myInit.method = "POST"; 
     myInit.body = JSON.stringify(data.body);
     myInit.headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     };
     let myRequest = new Request(data.url, myInit);
     return fetch(myRequest).then(
        res => res.json()
     );
  }
  let response = await getApi(dataRuby);
  console.log(response);
})()
```

Access to fetch at http://IP_address/index from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: What is your end goal? Are you trying to integrate a non-native shipping carrier and show rates from that carrier in the checkout?

Comment: I want to create some block at the product page were customer can write his zip code and after clicking "send" he will receive shipping cost data from UPS and USPS carriers. Our market has similar functionality at the cart page but I want to add something like this https://ibb.co/5hzGchS to the product page

Comment: As an aside, I'd suggest taking a look at the BigCommerce Shipping Provider API as a more natively integrated option for interacting with a rate service (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/store-management/shipping/shipping-provider-api), but more details about your CORS config would be helpful for troubleshooting. Are you using something like this? https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

Comment: Thank you for that advice but I have resolved my problem using standard Stencil Utils API of BigCommerce (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/adding-event-hooks-to-your-theme/stencil-utils-api-reference). I realized following chain of requests: added item to cart ->received shipping quotes -> deleted item from cart

Comment: Nice solution! Wish I had thought of that :) Thanks for following up to share.